# How to change localhost to a specific URL for external access in a Whisper application?

Tags: python, localhost, openai-whisper, gradio, a-records

I have a Whisper application running on my localhost under a specific port. Now, I want to make this application accessible to external users via a specific URL, such as "Whisper.test.com". I have already set up an A record at my provider pointing to the server IP of my Ubuntu server.

My question is, where exactly do I need to make changes to replace "localhost" with "Whisper.test.com" so that external users can access the application? Should I modify configuration files within the Whisper application itself, or are there settings at the server level that need adjustment?

Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried like starting the app.py file with "--share" - which creates an extern link for like 72 hours, but not with the specific URL which i want. I also tried with the argument "--server_name" - thats actually what i want, but its just accessable for me, like its just accessable from inside the server, so that means it still runs on localhost.

This is i think the most important parts, where to make changes with reference to the "server name". This is a part from the app.py file, which you also can find under the following link:

https://github.com/jhj0517/Whisper-WebUI/blob/master/app.py

```
        # Launch the app with optional gradio settings
        launch_args = {}
        if self.args.share:
            launch_args['share'] = self.args.share
        if self.args.server_name:
            launch_args['server_name'] = self.args.server_name
        if self.args.server_port:
            launch_args['server_port'] = self.args.server_port
        if self.args.username and self.args.password:
            launch_args['auth'] = (self.args.username, self.args.password)
        self.app.queue(api_open=False).launch(**launch_args)


# Create the parser for command-line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--disable_faster_whisper', type=bool, default=False, nargs='?', const=True, help='Disable the faster_whisper implementation. faster_whipser is implemented by https://github.com/guillaumekln>
parser.add_argument('--share', type=bool, default=False, nargs='?', const=True, help='Gradio share value')
parser.add_argument('--server_name', type=str, default=None, help='Gradio server host')
parser.add_argument('--server_port', type=int, default=None, help='Gradio server port')
parser.add_argument('--username', type=str, default=None, help='Gradio authentication username')
parser.add_argument('--password', type=str, default=None, help='Gradio authentication password')
parser.add_argument('--theme', type=str, default=None, help='Gradio Blocks theme')
parser.add_argument('--colab', type=bool, default=False, nargs='?', const=True, help='Is colab user or not')
_args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App(args=_args)
    app.launch()
```

I looked up also over here (link below), and i think thats the solution but i couldnt really figure it out where exactly to setup those changes, so would be really thankfull if anybody can help me with this:
https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/issues/260

Comment: once i start it with " python app.py --server_name: xy.test.com i get the error: ERROR:    [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 7863): cannot assign requested address

Comment: can anybody help me with that problem? i cant bind on the address. It has nothin to do with the ports.